# How do I locate an element from a web click?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[Python-selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) has examples of locating elements based on id, class, name, xpath, etc.

How would I go about locating elements based on the click location from the mouse?

Comment: Can you give an example scenario?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The x/y coordinates? Because you normally don't locate elements based on a mouse click location.

Comment: Is this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775351/clicking-at-coordinates-without-identifying-element?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do, the below command gets the currently active element (In your case , you will get element where the mouse is blinking )

```
elem = driver.switch_to.active_element
```

and you could also get the web element tag as

```
val = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Print the val and you can see the html of the element identified by the click

```
print(val)  #this gives the full html of that particular element eg <div id="answer-42436" class="answer" data-answerid="42436" itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
```

Comment: Please put some comments when downvoting, help others know what is the better approach than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the absolute x and y values then try this code.

```
# maximize the browser window so that you can get the absolute x and y based on the window inner and outer heights
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to OP
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")

# get to ask question element    
askQuestion = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ask Question")

# get the browser panel height
panel_height = driver.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')

# get the absolute x value    
abs_x = askQuestion.location['x']

# get y value    
y = askQuestion.location['y']
abs_y = y + panel_height

# print x and y values
print ("Absolute x : " + abs_x)
print ("Absolute y : " + abs_y)
```

Also, you can try this using [this](https://chercher.tech/python/mouse-actions-python-selenium)

Comment: Hello, @user43474 have you tried?